# Filter instances by name with Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Using the Blender-OSM addon I get thousands of buildings, wheras important buildings are listed by their names, unimportant buildings match the pattern "element.*" (see picture below).

[image]

To only view the named buildings, I want to filter the corresponding instances with the means of Geometry Nodes. However, there is **no data-type String** for the **Named-Arribute Node**. So I wonder how to retrieve this named attribute "Name" on instances? Couldn't find anything ... .
Is there another possibility to achieve my goal or is this only possible with Python scripting?

Comment: no, no strings fields yet. though you should know that the order ofvthe index of the instances is based on alphabetical order of their names.